# Eajaxupload shows "failed" everytime

Tags: ajax, file-upload, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to use eajaxupload extension to handle file uploading in my website. I followed the instruction [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload/) exactly and encountered a problem: it failed every time I uploaded a valid file (the validation against invalid file works well). I googled it and found a possible solution [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24279-eajaxupload-failed-upload/), but I did not succeed.
This is in my controller:

```
public function actionUpload() {
    Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");

    $folder='upload/';// folder for uploaded files
    $allowedExtensions = array("zip","rar","7z");//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
    $sizeLimit = 5 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
    $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
    $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

    $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
    $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME

    echo $return;// it's array
}
```

This is in my view:

```
$this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
    array(
    'id'=>'uploadFile',
    'config'=>array(
           'action'=>$this->createUrl('ProjectController/upload'),
           'allowedExtensions'=>array("zip","rar","7z"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
           'sizeLimit'=>5*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
           //'minSizeLimit'=>10*1024*1024,// minimum file size in bytes
           //'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",
           //'messages'=>array(
           //                  'typeError'=>"{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
           //                  'sizeError'=>"{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
           //                  'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
           //                  'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
           //                  'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
           //                 ),
           //'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"
          )
    ));
```

Please tell me if I went wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It work for me:

`$folder=Yii::app() -> getBasePath() . "/../images/uploads/"`

my directory is:

"Mysite/images/uploads"

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you really sure that there is 'upload/' folder in your project?
2. My $folder variable:

   ```
   $folder = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It work for me:

```
$folder = Yii::app()->basePath . '/uploads/documents/';
```

Where my root folder is:

```
c:\wamp\www\protected\uploads\documents\
```

View file:

```
<?php $this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
                array(
                        'id'=>'uploadFile',
                        'config'=>array(
                            'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('documents/addDocumentActivitatByAjax').'/'.$modelActivitat->id,
                            'allowedExtensions'=>array('jpeg','jpg','gif','png','txt','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','xml','ppt','pptx','pdf', 'vsd'),
                            'sizeLimit'=>10*1024*1024,// Tamaño máximo del fichero en bytes (10M)
                            'minSizeLimit'=>1024,// Tamaño minimo del fichero en bytes
                            'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ 
                                                            if(responseJSON.success){ 
                                                                var msg = JSON.stringify(responseJSON);
                                                                addFlashMessage(msg);
                                                                $('#documents-grid').yiiGridView.update('documents-grid'); 
                                                            }
                                                        }", 
                            ),
                )); ?>
```

Controller:

```
/**
         * Recibe por ajax un campo tipo 'file' y lo guarda como 'documents'
         * @param id Recibido por GET como parametro es el valor asignado al campo 'id_relacio' del Document a crear
         */
        public function actionAddDocumentActivitatByAjax(){
            $id_relacio = isset($_GET['id'])? $_GET['id'] : null;
            if(!empty($id_relacio)){
                $this->addDocument(LEME_DOCUMENTS_TIPUS_RELACIO_ACTIVITAT, $id_relacio);
            }else{
                echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode(array('success'=>'false', 'error'=>'No s\'ha rebut el id de l\'activitat associada')), ENT_NOQUOTES);
            }
        }

/**
         * Recibe por ajax un campo tipo 'file' y lo guarda como 'documents'
         * @param tipus_relacio Id del tipo de relación que guardará el Document
         * @param id Recibido como parametro es el valor asignado al campo 'id_relacio' del Document a crear
         */
        public function addDocument($tipus_relacio, $id_relacio){
            Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");

            $folder = Yii::app()->basePath.$this->carpetaContingut;
//            $allowedExtensions = array('jpeg','jpg','gif','png','txt','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','xml','ppt','pptx','pdf', 'vsd');
//            $sizeLimit = 25 * 1024 * 1024;// 25M

            $uploader = new qqFileUploader();
            $originalName = $uploader->file->getName();
            $originalName = SettingHelper::eliminaAcentos($originalName);
            // Guardamos el archivo con nombre 'MD5()'
            $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);

            if(!isset($result['error'])){
                // Si se sube bien generamos el registro en documents y renombramos el archivo recien subido a 'idDocument-NombreArchivoSubido.ext'
//                $result['fileSize'] = filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
                $fileNameMD5=$result['filename']; // Nombre del fichero guardado en encriptado en MD5
                $document = new Documents();
                $document->tipus_relacio = $tipus_relacio; // ID referent al tipus de relacio segons la taula vinculada
                $document->id_relacio = $id_relacio;    // ID del registre al que pertany
                $document->path = $this->carpetaContingut;
                if($document->save()){
                    // Renombramos el archivo recien subido con el nuevo nombre : 'idDocument-NombreArchivoSubido.ext'
                    $newName = $document->id.'-'.$originalName;
                    if(rename($folder.$fileNameMD5, $folder.$newName)){ 
                    // Si se renombra, hacemos update del 'document' con el nombre del archivo final
                        $document->url = $newName;
                        $document->save();
                        $return = array('success'=>'true', 'estat'=>'success', 'text'=> 'El fitxer "'.$newName.'" s\'ha guardat correctament.');
                    }
                }else{ // si da error al generar el document eliminamos el fichero recién subido.
                    unlink($folder.$fileNameMD5);
                    $return = array('success'=>'false', 'error'=> 'Error al generar el registre "document" associat.');
                }
            }else{ //Si da error al subir el fichero
                $return = $result;
            }

            echo CJSON::encode($return);
    }
```

Comment: please provide more details for the questioner

Answer (score 0):

You need to open php.ini file and make following changes:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M //Change to upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

and

```
post_max_size = 2M // Change to 50M
```

Restart the Apache Sever and there you go!